# calabash-android test fails in circleci, but successful during local testing

Tags: calabash, circleci, calabash-android

I'm using calabash-android version- 0.9.0 , the ruby  version: 2.2.0 . its integrated with circleci. after execution of few steps in calabash test, the test fails. but the same test passes when tested locally. is it any issue related to version?.

Someone please help to get this solved

```
features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:41
    And I press button with text "CONTINUE"                                                                                    # features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:60
      Failed to perform gesture. Could not find views '[* id:'but_next']' (RuntimeError)
      ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:63:in `/^I press button with text "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/my_first.feature:11:in `And I press button with text "CONTINUE"'
```